# How can i handle a camera direction parallel to the y-axis my raytracer

Tags: raytracing

I'm working on my raytracer and it seems I can't manage to handle the case where the direction vector of my camera is parallel to the vector (0,1,0).

I think it is linked to my way to compute the vector up and right for camera but I can't manage to find a work around.

Here is how I do it:

```
cam_up = vector_cross(cam_dir, {0, 1, 0});
camp_right = vector_cross(cam_right, cam_dir);
```

Can somebody enlighten me?

Comment: You need to add a programming language tag.

Comment: What direction do you want to choose in that case anyway?

Comment: i don't understand. What do you mean by choosing a direction?

Comment: The cross product didn't work out because what you're asking for is inherently ambiguous - it couldn't give an answer if it wanted to. Since the two vectors are parallel, essentially you're asking for "here is a direction, give me something perpendicular to it" - well, there's a lot of that. There's a whole plane to choose from. So you have to make the choice.

Comment: Can i choose something like {1, 0 ,0} as a replacement?

Comment: i did and it worked. thx a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the correct formula for calculation of an orthogonal axis from a single cameraOut vector. However, as has been stated this formula will not account for the camera roll, which could be any direction in the plane perpendicular to the camera direction. This will be apparent when moving a camera across the pole (y-axis) as there will be undesireable behavior (yes it will be correctly aimed, but no doubt the roll won't be desired).

For more information, look into [gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock).

The roll itself is not really incorrect, however in reality for this camera transition to be smooth and appear correct (rather than suddenly flip or spin as it's direction becomes 0,1,0), you need to correct any roll incurred. This is a rotation about the cameraOut axis and ideally should be relative to the previous cameraAlong. This means in order to maintain the correct roll (or perceived correct roll) you need to consider the camera POSE (position and orientation) from the previous frame and ensure the roll is mitigated. Of course, if the camera doesn't move (i.e. your rendering a frame with a static camera position) you do not have a previous camera state so the position cannot be calculated and instead must be explicitly defined as part of the scene definition.

Personally I store an entire orthogonal axis for a camera so the orientation and roll is always clearly defined. This is only for completeness, to be honest you don't need to store the entire axis, 2 vectors cameraOut and cameraAlong (the third one being cameraUp) are enough. cameraAlong is dependant on the handed-ness of your coordinate system (e.g. for initial camera position say position (0,0,0) in left hand coordinate system, the cameraAlong direction will be in the right direction in relation to the viewer, for right hand system the cameraAlong would be the other way around. The cameraUp and cameraOut would are the same in both coordinate systems).

Hope this helps.

P.S This isn't ray tracing specific and the same principles apply for OpenGL/DirectX or any 3D representation.